# Video listener does not automatically return to the menu

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to add a `goToAndStop` event when a video finishes playing in `ActionScript3`. It worked except it requires the user to click the "home" button to get back to the menu when a video finishes instead of automatically dropping back to menu frame.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please share your code so we can recommend improvements.